# How do I stop my Flash (AS3) program's framerate from dropping when users go to a new tab in their browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Every time I run my Flash program in a browser, the framerate drops from 30 to ~2 whenever I go to a different tab. Is there a way to stop the background framerate from tanking whenever the window isn't in focus? The framerate doesn't go down if I open a new window in the browser, even if the window covers the window with the Flash program. I'm also working in FlashDevelop if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can prevent this, it's a "performance feature". If your code relies on the frame rate, you might need to refacor it so it relies on the amount of time that has passed instead. Sorry this is vague, but perhaps if you clarify the problem you're facing someone can offer a more concrete solution.

Comment: Yeah, browsers will throttle the framerate down if the browser thinks the swf isn't showing.  It happens when swf is scrolled out of view too.

Comment: I ended up going with what Sunil D. suggested. Instead of just trying to make the program run while out of focus, I just made it calculate how many times the game would've updated (in frames) between when the SWF lost focus and when it gained focus again, and adjust accordingly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unearthed some source code from 2014 and found what I ended up going with:

**HUD.as:**

```
    public var idle:Boolean = false;
    public var catchingUp:Boolean = false;
    private var secondsIdle:int = 0;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, StartIdleMode);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, RegainedFocus);

    public function Update(sta:DisplayObjectContainer, save:SharedObject):void
    {
        //...The game logic that happens every frame...
        if (secondsIdle < 0)
        {
            idle = true;
        }
    }

    private function StartIdleMode(e:Event):void
    {
        var date:Date = new Date();
        secondsIdle = date.valueOf();
    }

    private function RegainedFocus(e:Event):void
    {
        if (idle)
        {
            var diffDate:Date = new Date();
            secondsIdle += -(diffDate.valueOf() / 2);
            catchingUp = true;
        }
    }

    public function CatchUp(sta:DisplayObjectContainer, save:SharedObject):void
    {   
        var tempFrames:int = Math.floor(secondsIdle / 1000 * 30);

        while (tempFrames < 0)
        {
            this.Update(sta, save);
            tempFrames++;
        }
        idle = false;
        catchingUp = false;
        secondsIdle = 0;
    }
```

**Main.as:**

```
    private var gameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000 / 30, 0);
    private var hud:HUD;

    public function Main():void
    {
        gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, GameLoop);
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    private function GameLoop(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        if (!hud.idle)
        {
            hud.Update(stage, gameSystem.saveData);
        }

        if (hud.catchingUp)
        {
            hud.CatchUp(stage, gameSystem.saveData);
        }
    }
```